# Macro expansion contains free variable

Tags: scala, scala-macros

My code compiles with the following error: `Macro expansion contains free term variable Hello ...`
I have reduced it to minimal example:

```scala
class Hello(val hi: String) {
  val xx = reify(hi)
  var yy = q""
}

def setYYImpl(c: Context)(hExpr: c.Expr[Hello]): c.Expr[Hello] = {
  import c.universe._
  val hello = c.eval(c.Expr[Hello](c.untypecheck(hExpr.tree.duplicate)))
  val xxVal = c.internal.createImporter(u).importTree(hello.xx.tree)
  c.Expr(q"""{val h = new Hello("HO"); h.yy=$xxVal; h}""") // it should set `h.yy` to Tree:"HO"
}

def setYY(hExpr: Hello): Hello = macro setYYImpl


setYY(new Hello("HI"))
```

After inspecting similar question: [Can this free-term-variable error (produced at macro expansion) be avoided?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029675/can-this-free-term-variable-error-produced-at-macro-expansion-be-avoided)

I have come to conclusion that the problem is `reify(hi)` which refers to the compile time value `Hello.hi`.

Is it possible to work around this problem? `reify(hi)` returns Expr `Hello.hi`, can I somehow remove the `Hello.` prefix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to replace

```
val xx = reify(hi)
```

with

```
val xx = Literal(Constant(hi))
```

i.e. build the tree manually (and 
`.importTree(hello.xx.tree)`
with
`.importTree(hello.xx)`).

(If it's `Literal(Constant...` only in your example and more complex tree in actual use case, anyway try to build it manually rather than use `reify`.)

Then you'll have different error

```
Error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("HI")
 required: reflect.runtime.universe.Tree
  setYY(new Hello("HI"))
```

because your macro returns

```
Expr[Hello]({
  val h = new Hello("HO");
  h.yy = "HI"; // h.yy is q"" i.e. Tree, "HI" is String
  h
})
```