# Creation trees with reify error: Macro expansion contains free term variable c

Tags: scala, reflection, metaprogramming, scala-macros

```
Scala 2.13.2
```

I'm learning how to create trees with reify as specified in the [documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#tree-creation-via-reify) and here is my toy macro attempt:

**I.**

```
def hasErrors: Boolean = macro impl

def impl(c: blackbox.Context): c.Expr[Boolean] = {
  import c.universe._
  c.Expr(reify(c.hasErrors).tree) //error
}
```

The macro invocation fails with the following error:

```
Main.scala:21:17: Macro expansion contains free term variable c defined by impl in Main.scala:11:12. 
Have you forgotten to use splice when splicing this variable into a reifee? 
If you have troubles tracking free term variables, consider using -Xlog-free-terms
```

**II.**

I tried to add `splice`, but got the same error:

```
def hasErrors: Boolean = macro impl

def impl(c: blackbox.Context): c.Expr[Boolean] = {
  import c.universe._
  reify(reify(c.hasErrors).splice) //error
}
```

**III.**

Writing the tree manually works fine:

```
def hasErrors: Boolean = macro impl

def impl(c: blackbox.Context): c.Expr[Boolean] = {
  import c.universe._
  c.Expr(Literal(Constant(c.hasErrors))) //compiles fine
}
```

**What is the problem with `reify` here and how to fix it?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56977467/macro-expansion-contains-free-variable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029675/can-this-free-term-variable-error-produced-at-macro-expansion-be-avoided

Comment: You can also write a quasiquote `c.Expr(q"${c.hasErrors}")`.